# How can I make my div tab to disabled cannot click in

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to make my some of my tab disable when editable is set to false:

Here is my following code:

```
  const tabs = [
    "Mission",
    "Agreement",
    "Calendar",
    "Managers",
    "Members",
    "Invitees",
    "Applicants",
  ];

<div className="team-management">
  <div className="team-management-tabs-header">
    <div className="team-management-tab-items">
      {tabs.map((tab, index) => (
        <div
          className={
            activeTab === index
              ? "team-management-tab-item selected"
              : "team-management-tab-item"
          }
          key={tab}
          role="button"
          tabIndex={tab}
          onKeyPress={() => {
            return;
          }}
          onClick={() => setActiveTab(index)}
        >
          <span className="tab-item-text">{tab}</span>
          <span className="tab-item-indicator" />
        </div>
      ))}
    </div>
  </div>

<div className="team-management-tab-panes">
        {tabs[activeTab] === "Mission" && (
          <Mission
            editable={editable}
            teamId={teamId}
            teamData={teamData}
            fetchTeamData={fetchTeamData}
          />
        )}

    ...

      </div>
```

Here is how my page look like:

[image]

How can I add disabled to my div in this situation?

thank you for helping.

Comment: How about adding a return state for disabled state in your div ? And to give more user feedback, perhaps on hovering over a disabled tab, you can set `cursor: not-allowed;` in it's styling ?

Comment: [Disable tab conditionally in React-Bootstrap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51250541/disable-tab-conditionally-in-react-bootstrap)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If editable was a state then you can  conditionally choose to fire the setActiveTab() function (considering that is the function that enables your tab and you want it disabled ) based on the state of editable.

```
onClick={() => if(editable)setActiveTab(index)}
```

Comment: Can I add specific tab that user cant click in? instead of all tab

Comment: It would be pretty similar. Just choose to conditionally fire setActiveTab based on its index. Ex: onClick={() => if(index===3)setActiveTab(index)}